# Laravel Slack Notification not sent when using implements ShouldQueue

Tags: php, laravel, slack, laravel-notification

I am struggling with dispatching a Slack notification when the Notification class implements ShouldQueue.

This is how I dispatch the notification

```
    /**
     * Handles the sendout of booking request confirmation to the customer 
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function sendCustomerNotifications()
    {
        $this->booking->customer->notify((new CustomerBookingRequested($this->booking)));
    }
```

This is how I my CustomerBookingRequested notification class looks like

```
class CustomerBookingRequested extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    private $booking;
    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Booking $booking)
    {
        //
        $this->booking = $booking;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail','slack'];
    }
    ...
    //code for toMail
    ...

    /**
     * Get the Slack representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Message\SlackMessage
     */
    public function toSlack($notifiable)
    {

        return (new SlackMessage)
                        ->success()
                        ->content('New booking requested!');
    }
```

My Customer Model uses Notifiable

```
class Customer extends Model implements HasLocalePreference
{
    use HasFactory;
    use Billable;
    use SoftDeletes;
    use Notifiable;
...
```

I also added to my Customer Model the routing method

```
/**
     * Route notifications for the Slack channel.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Notifications\Notification  $notification
     * @return string
     */
    public function routeNotificationForSlack($notification)
    {
        return env('SLACK_WEBHOOK');
    }
```

When I remove *implements ShouldQueue* from my Notification class, both Slack and Mail Message is sent. When I keep  implements ShouldQueue, the Mail message is sent, Slack message is not sent.

I basically want to send the customer a mail notification with a booking confirmation. At the same time I want to send a Slack message to the team's slack workspace. That's why I just added a static webhook URL in the customer model which is linked to the company's slack workspace.

I am a bit stuck here. Probably it's something obvious, but I can't find what I do wrong.

Thanks for your support!

```
Using Laravel 8.0 with "laravel/slack-notification-channel": "^2.3"
```

Comment: Is your queue worker running?

Comment: Yes it's running ;) I also do see 2 jobs dispatched in the jobs database table. One for mail, one for slack. But the slack message is not sent, only the mail message.

Comment: Check the logs; it may fail to authenticate.

Comment: The exact same code works when removing the implements ShouldQueue part. So the authentication works fine with slack. 
No exception is thrown.

Comment: Make sure your user exists in the database if not then you need to send an on-demand notification. 

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#on-demand-notifications

Answer (score 1):

Move the `SLACK_WEBHOOK` env variable to a config.

File: `config/sample.php`

```
return [
    'url' => env('SLACK_WEBHOOK')
];
```

Then reference the config from the Customer model.

File: `app/Models/Customer.php`

```
public function routeNotificationForSlack($notification) {
    return config('sample.url');
}
```

Comment: Lol van waneer of antwoord jy laravel vrae. Ek dog jy is 'n Slim framework fanboy :)

Comment: Haha well spotted! Ek het Slimmer geword.

Comment: Nice well done. Dis Timo btw. Ek het nounet actually 'n klein devops projek gedoen in Laravel. Dis nogal fun!